# Rewrite rule for trying 2 locations

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have 2 WordPress websites on the same VPS. One `/var/www/live/` and one `/var/www/dev/`. I want the following rule for `wp-content/uploads` on dev: if file exists on dev, show this file, if not, get file thru web from live. My .htacces:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://live.site/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't understand, how to combine 2 last rules, because first rule breaks second. If I comment first rule, WordPress working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://live.site/wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```